# Olá, queria fazer uma Progressbar com tkinter, podem me ajudar?

Tags: tkinter

Queria que quando eu apertasse o botão ela começasse e quando chegasse no final desaparecesse, porem nem a barra nem o botão aparecem na janela criada, ele não dispara nem um erro na tela.podem me ajudar?

Aqui segue o código que estou usando:

```
from tkinter import ttk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def _init_(self,*args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk._(self,*args, **kwargs)        
        self.button = ttk.Button(text = 'play', command = self.start)
        self.button.pack()
        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient = "horizontal", length = 200, mode = "determinate")
        self.progress.place(x = 0, y = 10)
        self.bytes = 0
        self.maxbytes = 0

    def start(self):
        self.progress['values'] = 0
        self.maxbytes = 50000
        self.progress['maximun'] = 50000
        self.read_bytes()


    def read_bytes (self):
        self.bytes += 500
        self.progress['values'] = self.bytes

        if self.bytes < self.maxbytes:
            self.after(100, self.read_bytes)

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você não colocou *underline* duplo na criação do construtor. O que você fez foi colocar `_init_` quando devia colocar `__init__`, dessa forma o programa nunca entrava no método.

Um outro erro que você cometeu foi ao chamar o construtor de `Tk`. Você utilizou um único *underline* ao invés de chamar o método `__init__`.

Veja abaixo o método corrigido:

```
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args, **kwargs)

        self.button = ttk.Button(text = 'play', command = self.start)
        self.button.pack()

        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient = "horizontal", length = 200, mode = "determinate")
        self.progress.place(x = 0, y = 10)

        self.bytes = 0
        self.maxbytes = 0
```

---

Saindo agora da parte da construção de sua interface gráfica, existe um outro problema no seu código referente ao `ProgressBar`.

Você está tentando avançar a barra de progresso através do atributo `values` que nem sequer existe. Para utilizar a barra de progresso corretamente, você deve criar um objeto de `IntVar`e linka-lo a seu `ProgressBar`.

Para definir o avanço da barra, mude o valor do seu objeto de `IntVar` através do método `set`. Dessa forma, seu programa funcionará perfeitamente.

```
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args, **kwargs)

        self.button = ttk.Button(text = 'play', command = self.start)
        self.button.pack()

        self.var_aux = tk.IntVar()

        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(
            self, orient = "horizontal",
            length = 200, mode = "determinate",
            variable = self.var_aux
            )

        self.progress.place(x = 0, y = 10)

        self.bytes = 0
        self.maxbytes = 0

    def start(self):

        self.maxbytes = 50000
        self.progress['maximum'] = self.maxbytes
        self.read_bytes()


    def read_bytes(self):

        self.bytes += 500
        self.var_aux.set(self.bytes)

        if self.bytes < self.maxbytes:
            self.after(100, self.read_bytes)
```

Comment: Obrigado! funcionou.

Comment: e como faço para quando a progressbar chegar no final o programa execute uma ação?

Comment: Aí você vai ter que criar seu próprio código para verificar o andamento do progressbar e fazer algo.